# It is necessary to generate the swagger json correctly

Tags: laravel, swagger, swagger-editor, swagger-php

The problem is that I need the documentation to show that it is possible to transfer the field colums in the form of an array and in it the following fields (name, description, created_at, updated_at, author). json is successfully generated but in the swagger-editor documentation it is not visible these fields

```
 /**
         * @SWG\Get(path="/articles",
         *   tags={"Article"},
         *   summary="Get all Articles",
         *   description="Show list of Articles",
         *   operationId="all",
         *   produces={"application/json"},
         *   @SWG\Parameter(
         *     name="columns",
         *     in="query",
         *     description="get specific columns",
         *     required=false,
         *     type="array",
         *     collectionFormat="multi",
         *     @SWG\Items(
         *       type="string",
         *          @SWG\Property(property="name", type="string"),
         *          @SWG\Property(property="description", type="string"),
         *          @SWG\Property(property="author", type="string"),
         *          @SWG\Property(property="created_at", type="string"),
         *          @SWG\Property(property="updated_at)", type="string")
         *      )
         *   ),
         *   @SWG\Response(response="200"),
         *   @SWG\Response(response=500)
         *   ),
         * )
         */
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of how the full request URL with the query string is supposed to look like? E.g. how `author`, `created_at` etc. are supposed to be serialized into the query string.

Comment: @Helen  example.com/articles?columns[]=name&columns[]=description       but this is not so important because in other methods, for example, the create does not show the fields in the array data